# Swiper - When browser is resized, image must remain 100% viewable

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

Using jQuery 3.1.1, Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Swiper 3.4.1, I want to display a Swiper gallery full screen but have it so the image is always viewable without the need to scroll, especially when the browser is resized.

Using the code supplied, I can display the Swiper gallery and the image remains visible on the X-axis only, but the Y-axis causes the page to scroll vertically.

What am I doing wrong to cause it to auto-adjust the height when the window width is changed but not auto-adjust the width when the window height changes, resulting in the vertical scroll bar?

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gfomsmov/)

### HTML

```
<div class="viewer">
  <div class="swiper-container" id="popupGallery">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_1.jpg">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_2.jpg">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_3.jpg">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_4.jpg">
      <img class="swiper-slide" src="https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="popupGalleryPrev" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2;"></div>
    <div class="popupGalleryNext" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 50%; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.viewer {
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

### JS

```
var popupGallery = new Swiper('#popupGallery', {
  loop: true,
  nextButton: '.popupGalleryNext',
  prevButton: '.popupGalleryPrev',
  spaceBetween: 2
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make a picture auto adjust it's width and height and always fill the screen (X-axis) without stretching it.

I don't know if there's a solution with img-Tags (without stretching it), but you could archive what you want if you use a background image.

Just give the wrapper a `max-height: 100vh;` (vh is 100% of the viewport height) and set the background-images to `background-size: contain;`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfomsmov/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="viewer">
  <div class="swiper-container" id="popupGallery">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="popupGalleryPrev" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2;"></div>
    <div class="popupGalleryNext" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 50%; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.viewer {
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.swiper-slide {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_1.jpg');
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_2.jpg');
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_3.jpg');
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_4.jpg');
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_5.jpg');
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(6) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_1.jpg');
}
.swiper-slide:nth-of-type(7) {
  background-image: url('https://static.reades.co.uk/1001-487d/0/image_2.jpg');
}
```

Although, you'll get some nasty gaps between your pictures.. You could add another div and center it within the swiper-slide..

Don't forget to add 2 more images in your css for the duplicated slides (because of the loop setting)

Hope that helps.